# How to write linq to sql or Sql query to search data from two tables using mvc

Tags: search, model-view-controller

I'm new to subsonic framework and i need help.
I have a question,

I need to provide search functionality on a mvc page. I need to use the search string to search for the text in two different sql tables say companies and registrations which are linked using companyid.

**- I'm trying to query as in linq**

```
var searchString = "PM";

   var registrations = (from r in _repo.All<Registration>()
                             join c in _repo.All<Company>() on r.CompanyId equals c.CompanyId
                             where r.IsSubmitted == false && r.approvaldate ==null
                                 (c.CompanyName.Contains(searchString) || r.CompanyEmail.Contains(searchString))
                             select r);
```

**and in sql query as**

```
select approvaldate,issubmitted,companyemail,* from registrations r 
where r.issubmitted='false' and r.approvaldate is null and (companyemail like '%pm%'
or companyid in (select companyid from companies where companyname like '%pm%'))
```

which i think is wrong, since its not getting the expected data.

Could anyone please help me to query it either using linq  or sql statement to use stored procedure would be grateful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query seems to contain subquery. however your linq query is a bit different.

I would do it like this:

```
   var registrations = (from r in _repo.All<Registration>()
                        join c in _repo.All<Company>() on r.CompanyId equals c.CompanyId
                        select (x=> new{
                        IsSubmitted = r.IsSubmitted ,
                        approvaldate =r.approvaldate,
                        CompanyName=c.CompanyName,
                        CompanyEmail=c.CompanyEmail
}); 

registrations=registrations.Where(x=> IsSubmitted == false && approvaldate ==null &&(CompanyName.Contains(searchString) || CompanyEmail.Contains(searchString))
```

you can include more columns in select list to display it as well.

Hope this helps.